# Can Linked Lists be only a single class?

Tags: python, recursion, linked-list, big-o, memoization

I have created a linked list, but after looking on the internet I only see linked lists containing 2 classes, 1 node and 1 linked list class and now I am worried mine is not a linked list at all.

Below is code I have written for a linked list, but am now worried this isn't a linked list and instead more similar to a binary tree.

```
import random
cache = {}
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        
        self.head = None
        self.data = data

    def insert(self, data):
      if self.data:
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = Node(data)
        else:
            self.head.insert(data)
      else:
        self.data = data

    def PrintList(self):
      if self.head:
          self.head.PrintList()
      print( self.data ),

    def ListLength(self, length = 0):
      if self.head:
          return self.head.ListLength(length + 1)
      return length

    def PrintListRandomKnownNodes(self, randnode, count = 0):
        if randnode == count:
          return self.data
        
        if self.head:
          return self.head.PrintListRandomKnownNodes(nodeamount, count + 1)
        
        return self.data

    def printRandomUnknownNodes(self):
      
        if self.data:
            cache[self] = self.data

        if self.head:
            return self.head.printRandomUnknownNodes()
        
        res = random.choice(list(cache.values()))
        return res
 
LList = Node(1)

nodes = random.randrange(5, 10)

for x in range(0, 10):
  # LList.counter = LList.counter + 1
  LList.insert(x + random.randrange(5, 100))

LList.PrintList()

ListLength = LList.ListLength()
print("list length is ", ListLength)

randomNum = random.randint(0, ListLength)
print("randomnum",randomNum)

randomnode = LList.PrintListRandomKnownNodes(ListLength, randomNum)
print("random known node amount node data is:", randomnode)

cache = {}
randomunknownnode = LList.printRandomUnknownNodes()
print("random unknown node amount data is:", randomunknownnode)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't remove information from your post after it's been answered. Some of this code is redundant and can be safely removed, but things like the definition of your linked list class are vital context to the question at hand and should not be removed.

Comment: Remember that SO is a site for building a repository of knowledge; answerers aim to help not only you but future readers as well. Removing important context from your original question is antithetical towards that goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code represents a singly linked list. The number of classes used to represent a data structure and what data structure those classes represent do not necessarily have any connection with each other.